# Javascript: does importing a module change the encoding of strings in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding

I'm doing some simple web applications with Javascript (using Node.js and Express), and I just came across what seemed like a somewhat bizarre situation. Well, I'm relatively new to the language as a whole, so maybe it's not that uncommon, or I may be incurring in some basic mistake.

Anyway, I just realised that strings declared in the same module are acting different to those declared in different modules (and imported through the "require" statement). For instance, if I have this code sent to a simple template ('index.hbs') that just renders and displays the value of 'str':

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('index.hbs', {
        str: 'Français'
    });
});
```

The browser displays the result correctly in *utf-8*:

> Français

But if I instead put that string in another module, like this, for instance:

other.js

```
module.exports = 'Français';
```

and call it from the main function:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('index.hbs', {
        str: require('./other.js')
    });
});
```

Then the browser fails to read the special characters in *utf-8* resulting in:

> Fran�ais

So if I'm understanding this correctly, a change in encoding is happening during the code import from one module to another. Is this normal? what would be the best way to address the problem (i.e. making the strings from other modules stay in *utf-8*)?

Comment: Make sure your server is using the proper MIME headers (you can check with your browser developer tools)

Comment: you might try [decoding](http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html) the string using `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: What output do you see from `console.log(require('./other'))` server-side? If the console also shows `�` for `ç`, check the file encoding that `other.js` is being saved with.

Comment: **Pointy:** It seems charset is set to utf-8. Also, what I find weird is that if I use a string declared in the same module it works differently than the same string declared in a different module (this makes it seem like there is some encoding change happening in the javascript code itself during the import process).

Comment: **Jonathan Lonowski**: I'm using the GitBash console on Windows, and it shows '?' for non ascii characters either way. But I think you are right, and the other files might be encoded in something no-utf8. I will check that.

Comment: @Ninethousand Side-note: You can [use `@name` in a reply](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to another user. The comment editor will also help with auto-complete after typing the `@`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so as user *Jonathan Lonowski* pointed out, what was happening is that the files were not in utf-8, so importing strings declared as literals in them (in the example's case, *other.js*) did so in those files' own encoding.

Solving the problem was as easy as changing the encoding of all code files to utf-8, so when a string (or an object containing strings) is required elsewhere, the encoding remains utf-8.

Comment: there is a way to fix incorrect encoding from JS itself, but fixing the files is WAY simpler...